# Fork a repository between two corporate GitHub accounts with PyGithub

Tags: python, github

Our company shares a number of corporate code repos in a central company account; the URL is *https://github.com/COMPANY_NAME*.  When I'm logged in with my corporate username, I can access and fork repos under this account using Github's web interface.

My github corporate account is *https://github.com/mpennington-te*.  I routinely have to fork repos from *https://github.com/COMPANY_NAME* to *https://github.com/mpennington-te*.

Once I have forked a repo to mpennington-te, I clone *https://github.com/mpennington-te/REPO_NAME.git* to my laptop, do work, and then push the changes back to *https://github.com/mpennington-te/REPO_NAME.git*.

At this point, I submit pull requests in *https://github.com/COMPANY_NAME/REPO_NAME* to send my work upstream.

I am trying to automate some of this workflow, but I can't find anything in [PyGithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub) to fork a repo from *https://github.com/COMPANY_NAME/REPO_NAME* to *https://github.com/mpennington-te/REPO_NAME*.

I looked through the [PyGithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub) API for a way to do this and nothing jumps out...

```
import github
gg = github.Github('mpennington-te', "GITHUB-PERSONAL-ACCESS-TOKEN")
org = gg.get_organization('COMPANY_NAME')
repo = org.get_repo('REPO_NAME')
```

**Question**: How can I fork github repos like this with [PyGithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work...

```
>>> from github import Github
>>> gg = Github("USER_NAME", "GITHUB-PERSONAL-ACCESS-TOKEN")
>>> github_user = gg.get_user()
>>> repo = gg.get_repo('COMPANY_NAME/REPO_NAME')
>>> myfork = github_user.create_fork(repo)
>>> myfork
Repository(full_name="USER_NAME/REPO_NAME")
>>>
```

I found this embedded in [this PyGithub issue](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/issues/626)... The API is [documented](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Gist.html#github.Gist.Gist.create_fork), but the issue made usage more clear.

You can also `delete()` the fork:

```
>>> myfork.delete()
>>>
```